# Recv hangs even though I followed all conventions?

Tags: c, sockets, gcc, recv

I am trying to create a small program that takes a http requests through stdin and sends it to a server.
This is the code I am using:

```c
int portno =        3000;
char *message = buf;
char response[4096];
int byte_count;
fsize = strlen(message);
int sockfd;
/* fill in the parameters */
printf("Request:\n%s\n",message);

/* create the socket */
sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
if (sockfd < 0) error("ERROR opening socket");
int sz = (1024 * 1024);
if (setsockopt(sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_SNDBUF, &sz, sizeof(sz)) == -1) {
    perror("setsockopt");
    exit(1);
}
struct sockaddr_in saddr;
saddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
saddr.sin_port = htons(portno);
saddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_LOOPBACK);
if (connect(sockfd, &saddr, sizeof(saddr)) == -1) {
    perror("connect");
}
send(sockfd, message, fsize, MSG_NOSIGNAL);
printf("written");
byte_count = recv(sockfd,response,sizeof(response)-1,0); // <-- -1 to leave room for a null terminator
response[byte_count] = 0; // <-- add the null terminator
printf("recv()'d %d bytes of data in buf\n",byte_count);
printf("%s",response);
close(sockfd);
```

buf is equal to this

```
GET /alias%2Findex.html HTTP/1.0\r\n
\r\n
\r\n
\r\n
```

I have done some research through other stack overflow posts and they state that recv usually hangs when the system is waiting for a response. I do not know what could be causing this.

Comment: Does the buffer contain literal `\r` and `\n`, or are those CR and LF characters?

Comment: Those are the CR and LF characters.

Comment: When things don't work always check your return values. You currently have no idea if `send` succeeded or not. And check your `recv` return value. You'll be _lucky_ to get a segfault while writing to `response[-1]`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your program only slightly modified. And it works for me.
Are you certain whatever server you are running on localhost port 3000 is responding properly? BTW, I had to change the port to 8080 for my system.

```
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netinet/tcp.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <unistd.h>

char buf[1 << 16] = "GET /file.txt HTTP/1.0\r\n"
                    "\r\n"
                    "\r\n";

int main() {
  int portno = 8080;
  char *message = buf;
  int byte_count;
  int fsize = strlen(message);
  int sockfd;
  /* fill in the parameters */
  printf("Request:\n%s\n", message);

  /* create the socket */
  sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
  if (sockfd < 0)
    perror("ERROR opening socket");
  int sz = (1024 * 1024);
  if (setsockopt(sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_SNDBUF, &sz, sizeof(sz)) == -1) {
    perror("setsockopt");
    exit(1);
  }
  struct sockaddr_in saddr;
  saddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
  saddr.sin_port = htons(portno);
  saddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_LOOPBACK);
  if (connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&saddr, sizeof(saddr)) == -1) {
    perror("connect");
  }
  send(sockfd, message, fsize, MSG_NOSIGNAL);
  printf("written");
  while ((byte_count = recv(sockfd, buf, sizeof(buf) - 1, 0)) >
         0) {            // <-- -1 to leave room for a null terminator
    buf[byte_count] = 0; // <-- add the null terminator
    printf("recv()'d %d bytes of data in buf\n", byte_count);
    printf("%s", buf);
  }
  close(sockfd);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think I have found the problem too. I am trying to integrate this code into the server itself, and what happens is that before the server gets initialized, this code is ran.
How would I be able to create socket connection still?

Comment: I don't understand why you would want to run this kind of code inside the server code. But you would need to use asynchronous IO in the main event loop using whatever the server uses such as poll or select. Or you would need to run in a separate thread.